# Parse string to date without using system format

Tags: vb.net

Lets say I have a string like this: '24-11-2016' and I want to convert this to a date. Currently I use this code:

```
 SynResultatSynsDato = Date.ParseExact("24-11-2016", "dd-MM-yyyy",
                    System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

But this only works when I'm running this on a computer with the English dateformat. Is there anyway I can specify which format it should use.

Comment: is there a specific culture it fails on? *How* does it fail?  `Invariant` tells it to ignore the system culture settings for the format.  as long as the format string matches the layout of the data, it should work.  ex: "24-2016.11" which is just goofy parses fines using "dd-yyyy.MM"

Comment: Note that intellisense will **always** display it as `#MM/dd/yyyy#` (in VB), is that how you measure if it is working?

Comment: Plutonix I live in denmark and when i parse lets say Feb 1st I get Jan 2nd because time format it messed up: 1/2/2016 and 2/1/2016. This is a huge problem and since i wont be able to detect any errors in the first 12 days of each month since both the date and the month number can be swapped to list a different day. I get an error when i run my code on Danish time format on my computer, but if i change it to english format it can convert the text just fine. This is why i think its using my system default format to convert via my application !

Comment: I think @Plutonix is correct though that the problem is more likely to be later, where you use the `SynResultatSynsDato` variable, rather than at conversion - the code you posted should work no matter what culture is selected in Control Panel.

Comment: You are misdiagnosing the problem: `"dd-yyyy.MM"` is not a member of `cultureinfo.InvariantCulture` yet it can be used to parse the date.  Again, ***how*** do you know the result is wrong?  If you tell it "dd-MM" it will parse it to ""dd-MM"

Answer (score 0):

The following converts a date from English (Australian) format to Danish (Denmark) format.

```
Dim enAU As New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-AU")
Dim SynResultatSynsDato As Date
SynResultatSynsDato = Date.ParseExact("02 March 2016", "dd MMMM yyyy", enAU, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
Dim daDK As New Globalization.CultureInfo("da-DK")
MsgBox(SynResultatSynsDato.ToString("D", daDK)) 'Displays "2. marts 2016"
```